# Класс img-responsive (bootstrap) режет спрайт

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

`.img-responsive` режет спрайт:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 ">
            texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
            ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
            ttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttex
            ttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="photo ">
                <div class="photo__item photo__item_4 img-responsive"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.photo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 17px 20px 0;
}
.photo__item_4{
    background: #fff url("../images/img-sprite-sb432b0f395.png") 0px -2455px no-repeat;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    height: 104px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.img-responsive` здесь лучше не использовать - этот бутстраповский класс не сочетается с css-спрайтами. Потому что он влияет непосредственно на изображение, а здесь нужно повлиять и на его родителя (у вас это `.photo`).

Верстка будет такая:

```
<div class="photo photo_4">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_4"></div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на `photo_4` и `photo_item_4` - эти классы нужны для стилизации отдельного изображения спрайта.

> Для тестов я взял [вот этот спрайт](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/373_sprites/angry_birds.png), рабочий пример доступен здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/72Let9a4/

`.photo` мы подстраиваем под всю ширину контейнера:

```
.photo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

При этом `.photo_4` мы ограничиваем по ширине:

```
.photo_4 {
  max-width: 112px;
}
```

Где `112px` - это ширина отдельного изображения в спрайте. Обратите внимание - значение в пикселях.

Далее - стили самого изображения:

```
.photo__item {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

`width: 100%` растягивает изображение по родителю, то есть по `.photo`. Но, так как у `.photo` стоит ограничение в `112px` - изображение перестанет растягиваться на этой отметке.

`padding-bottom: 100%;` - важный атрибут. У нашего изображения высота равна нулю, но есть нижний паддинг, равный ширине контейнера `.photo`. В итоге фактическая высота нашего изображения будет равна его ширине, в том числе - и в случае с `112px`. Получаем резиновый квадрат. В него мы и будем ставить фоном спрайт.

> Если ваше изображение в спрайте не квадратное - тогда `padding-bottom` у вас будет отличаться. Например, если изображение размером `112px*83px`, тогда `padding-bottom` будет равен `83px / 112px = 0.7410 = 74.10%`

Когда ставим изображение фоном - все размеры мы указываем **в процентах**:

```
.photo__item_4 {
  background: #fff url("https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/373_sprites/angry_birds.png");
  background-position: 0 38.88%;
  background-size: 535.71% 357.14%;
}
```

Формулы расчета:

- Размер по ширине - `600px / 112px = 5.3571 = 535.71%`
- Размер по высоте - `400px / 112px = 3.5714 = 357.14%`
- Отступ по икс - `0px / ( 600px - 112px ) = 0`
- Отступ по игрек - `112px / ( 400px - 112px ) = 0.3888 = 38.88%`

Где:

- `600px` - ширина спрайта
- `400px` - высота спрайта
- `112px` в размере, а также внутри скобок в отступе - ширина и высота изображения в спрайте
- `0px` и `112px` за скобками в отступах - отступ изображения в спрайте по икс и игрек

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/72Let9a4/